# how to save bitmap to file using direct2d and ID2D1HwndRenderTarget

Tags: c++, bitmap, direct2d

[How to save ID2D1Bitmap to PNG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447489/how-to-save-id2d1bitmap-to-png-file) did not help me.

I'm working with Direct2D.

I want to save a `ID2D1**Hwnd**RenderTarget *m_pRenderTarget` to file as bmp or png etc.

But the sample I found on MSDN use `ID2D1RenderTarget`.

In my case I drawn my figure in m_pRenderTarget, I used the method `ID2D1Bitmap::CopyFromRenderTarget (...)`  to get an ID2D1Bitmap.

After that, to use the saving function bellow, I have to convert the `ID2D1Bitmap` I got to `IWICBitmap`. Because the function bellow doesn't use `ID2D1Bitmap` ...

I did not found yet how to do this.

thanks.

```
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{

    //
    // Save image to file
    //

    hr = pWICFactory->CreateStream(&pStream);
}

WICPixelFormatGUID format = GUID_WICPixelFormatDontCare;
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    static const WCHAR filename[] = L"output.png";
    hr = pStream->InitializeFromFilename(filename, GENERIC_WRITE);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pWICFactory->CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatPng, NULL, &pEncoder);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pEncoder->Initialize(pStream, WICBitmapEncoderNoCache);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pEncoder->CreateNewFrame(&pFrameEncode, NULL);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pFrameEncode->Initialize(NULL);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pFrameEncode->SetSize(sc_bitmapWidth, sc_bitmapHeight);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pFrameEncode->SetPixelFormat(&format);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pFrameEncode->WriteSource(pWICBitmap, NULL);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pFrameEncode->Commit();
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pEncoder->Commit();
}
```

to explain easily, I already had a Direct2D code and my drawing image is hold on my ID2D1HwndRenderTarget.  I want to save the drawn image hold by my ID2D1HwndRenderTarget on disk.

the sample I found create a new IWICBitmap, and with
         `pD2DFactory->CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget(pWICBitmap,D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),&pRT);`

```
create a new ID2D1RenderTarget to draw. After drawing operations, it wrote the bitmap image 
    hr = pFrameEncode->WriteSource(pWICBitmap, NULL);
```

In my case I don't know how to put the  image from my ID2D1HwndRenderTarget to IWICBitmap... to write it. someone have a clue with how to bind  ID2D1HwndRenderTarget and IWICBitmap

Comment: `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` just inherits from the `ID2D1RenderTarget`. So why didn't the sample help? Could you also post the link of the sample?

Comment: Hi, Here is a link for the code [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/d2dsaveasimage/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3071)  The sample didn't help because I used CComPtr<ID2D1Factory> m_fabriqueD2D1;
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *m_pRenderTarget;

Comment: Have you tried CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap then ID2D1Bitmap::CopyFromRenderTarget?